# Material UI Autocomplete Styles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I changed the MUI Autocomplete styles to customise it according to my need . Everything works fine until I add disableClearable={true} as prop . Somehow the styles get reset to default values .

```
               <Autocomplete
                className={classes.dropdown}
                options={someRandomOptions}
                getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
                renderInput={(params) => (
                  <TextField {...params} variant="outlined" />
                )}
                defaultValue={{ value: 7, label: "7 days" }}
                size="small"
              />
```

I am applying the class using makeStyles() , this is the object I am using :

```
dropdown: {
    "&.MuiAutocomplete-hasPopupIcon.MuiAutocomplete-hasClearIcon .MuiAutocomplete-inputRoot":
      {
        padding: "0px !important",
        fontSize: "14px",
        color: "#1E5EF3",
        fontWeight: 500,
      },
    "& .MuiAutocomplete-endAdornment": {
      right: "0px !important",
    },
    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      borderColor: "#1E5EF3",
    },
  },
```

These style are not getting applied if I add disableClearable to true.
I am using MUI v4 . Refer this link to see the issue by uncommenting the prop .

sandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-paper-77bnvc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/DropDown.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening because you have also used **.MuiAutocomplete-hasClearIcon**. and when you are doing disableClearable={true} the clear icon is not rendering and class is not applying. **To fix this issue just remove this class .MuiAutocomplete-hasClearIcon** from your custom css.like this:

```js
dropdown: {
    "&.MuiAutocomplete-hasPopupIcon .MuiAutocomplete-inputRoot":
      {
        padding: "0px !important",
        fontSize: "14px",
        color: "#1E5EF3",
        fontWeight: 500,
      },
    "& .MuiAutocomplete-endAdornment": {
      right: "0px !important",
    },
    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      borderColor: "#1E5EF3",
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using `MuiAutocomplete-hasClearIcon` class name, but `MuiAutocomplete-hasClearIcon` is applied **only** when the clear icon is rendered.
From Mui Documentation:

> hasClearIcon  .MuiAutocomplete-hasClearIcon   Styles applied when the clear icon is rendered.

If you want to use root class name, use `.MuiAutocomplete-root`

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  dropdown: {
    "&.MuiAutocomplete-root .MuiAutocomplete-inputRoot": {
      padding: "0px !important",
      fontSize: "14px",
      color: "#1E5EF3",
      fontWeight: 500
    },
    ...
  }
}));
```

You can review `Mui` `AutoComplete` class names from Documentation:
https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/#css